# Using v-for in a v-model, vuetify 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I have a v-for rendering trought input fields from the user and keep getting the same error. Somehow my property .begin from the element of the array is getting undefined

I just keep receiving the same error : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'begin')

Thats my template[enter image description he](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owo4N.png)re.

And that is my Script[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvUdI.png)

Comment: Please post code as text, not images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `HAcademico: [this.OneActivity, this.OneActivity]` in line 43, you are using `this` keyword to refer to same object, but `this` refers to `data()` context, so you need to do this:

```
data() {
    const oneActivity = {begin: '', end: '', type: '', text: ''}

    return {
        oneActivity,
        HAcademico: [oneActivity, oneActivity],
    }
}
```